# How to get proper JSON array of object out of this?

Tags: json, angular, api

API I'm working is giving me this {"data": [{object1}], [{object2}],..}, how to parse it into array of json objects? I'm trying to work with it in angular 4 and I'm not sure how to get for example {{object1.name}} in my ngFor loop?

```
          httpClient.get("users").subscribe((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
           });
```

and in my console there's a {data: Array(1)}

and if I try to iterate in my html component, this error shows up in console
           Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: You need to post your implementation of that API, how are you calling it

Comment: Not clear from your question, but it seems like the API you're interacting with is returning an Array of Arrays. If you provide an example of how you're fetching the data (Http/HttpClient) and and example of how the data is structured, then we can help more with. But in general it sounds like you need to use the `map` operator to flatten the response from the API.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here for us to help you at all.

Comment: edited question

Comment: your response is an object. so you cant iterate through it. either make your api return an array, or iterate through `response.data`

Comment: I can't make my api return an array, can u give me a simple example of respons.data?

Answer (score 0):

```
    getSomething() {
         return this._http.get(api/something)
        .map(res => res.json().data)
         .catch(this._errorHandler);
    }
```

.data solved my issue Error trying to diff '[object Object]'